# Setting up Spring Cloud Config Server with Git & Vault back-end for clients that don't send X-Config-Token header

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

I understand the setup for Spring Cloud Config Server with both Git & Vault backends. That is straightforward and works fine.

In our organization our Spring Cloud Config Server has clients that do not have anything stored in Vault. It seems though that Config Server still requires the `X-Config-Token` header from **ALL** clients, even if that client doesn't need anything from Vault.

Is there some option/setting somewhere where if Config Server doesn't see the `X-Config-Token` header then it just ignores the Vault backend for that request?

Comment: I have similar question for `git` and `oracle` backend. IMO, the config server does not uses the fallback approach, but instead uses the value selector approach (based on priority in case same key is found in multiple sources)